# Java Static Variables for Data Storage vs Local

Tags: java, inheritance, static, abstract, extends

I substituted animals for my real code, so it may seem a little silly but this is a real question.

My java program gets a list of different animals and iterates through them one at a time doing the following for each: Animal is created, the animal does some random movements, each movement is counted, then the program collects the movement data, does some analysis and goes on to the next Animal on the list.

I have an abstract Animal class that is extended by different animal objects, Dog, Cat etc. each with its own movements.  In that base Animal class there is a HashMap that counts the Animal's random movements.

Each movement method ends with a call to updateMap, which is in the Animal base class.  updateMap receives the movement String key as input, then checks if the given movement is in the HashMap as a key, if not, it adds the movement as a key, with the value being 1.  If the movement is already a key in the HashMap it will increment the number value.

The current set-up is the HashMap is in the Animal class and so each Animal has its own.  My question is, would it be against Java best practices to move the HashMap to a separate utility class as a static variable with a static updateMap method?  I would have to add a getter method to call when I want the movement data, and a method to clear the map that would be called in the Animal constructor.  The Animals are iterated through one at a time, and only once, so there wouldn't be a conflict with the updates.

The reason I want to create the static utility class is I hope it will improve performance.  The list of animals is millions of items long and I figured I'd be able to speed it up a little (even if it's barely noticeable) if each one doesn't have to be created with this HashMap as a class variable.  But I don't know if the calls to the static methods would slow it down.  Any opinions on that would be appreciated as well as if you know a better (performance-wise) design to keep track of the movements.

Pseudocode:

Current:

Animal.java

```
 public abstract class Animal {
      private HashMap counter;

      public Animal(String input){
           counter = new HashMap();
           .
           .
      }

      protected void updateMap(String key){
           if(counter.contains(key)){
                counter.update(key, counter.get(key)+1);
           } else {
                counter.add(key, 1);
           }
      }

      protected void analyze(){
           some code using counter;
      }
 }
```

Dog.java

```
 public class Dog extends Animal {

      public Dog(String input){
           super(input);
      }

      private void jump(){
           .
           .
           updateMap("jump");
      }

      private void run(){
           .
           .
           updateMap("run");
      }

      private void dance(){
           .
           .
           updateMap("dance");
      }
```

Change:

Animal.java

```
 public abstract class Animal {

      public Animal(String input){
           AnimalUtil.clearCounter();
           .
           .
      }

      protected void analyze(){
           HashMap count = AnimalUtil.getCounter();
           some code using counter;
      }
 }
```

Dog.java

```
 public class Dog extends Animal {

      public Dog(String input){
           super(input);
      }

      private void jump(){
           .
           .
           AnimalUtil.updateMap("jump");
      }

      private void run(){
           .
           .
           AnimalUtil.updateMap("run");
      }

      private void dance(){
           .
           .
           AnimalUtil.updateMap("dance");
      }
 }
```

AnimalUtil.java

```
 public class AnimalUtil {
      private static HashMap counter;

      public static void updateMap(String key){
           if(counter.contains(key)){
                counter.update(key, counter.get(key)+1);
           } else {
                counter.add(key, 1);
           }
      }

      public static HashMap getCounter(){
           return counter;
      }

      public static void clearCounter(){
           counter = new HashMap();
      }
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: We understand code. Post the code instead of describing it.

Comment: I partly agree with @JBNizet. I would say post code **as well as** describing it, though.

Comment: Added some rough code

Comment: Your suggestion will create as many HashMaps, take the same amount of time and memory, but you will lose many many interesting properties of your original code: you won't be able to use/analyze two animals at once, you won't be able to use/analize several animals in parallel, and you'll have to clear the map after your last analysis instead of just relying on the GC to do its job once your animals go out of scope. Global mutable state in general is a terrible idea, and this case is no exception.

Answer (score 1):

One question to ask yourself: does it make sense for each animal to have its own HashMap? It sounds like the answer is no since this is "shared" data that is "global".

Making this a `static` variable is reasonable. I suggest also considering other options. For example, it sounds like the HashMap stores information about the world where the animals live. So maybe this variable belongs in another class, `World` or `Farm`, instead of in the `Animal` class.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, most of the time when you create a utility class is because you don´t know the responsibility of the code that goes in there. The best practice in all languages according to Clean Code is that every peace of code you write has its own domain and its own responsibilities. So take the HashMap you want to use globally and put it in a class that has the responsibility to count and observe the movement of the different animals. That would be my suggestion.

Comment: Very good point. Each class should have one responsibility and do it well.